# How to use forEach or forEachValue method

Tags: java, foreach, iterator, enumeration

I have a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Document>` and I have to call a method to delete a file for each value.

Document is a class that represents a document as a file.

I found, on eclipse, forEach and forEachValue methods (with many signatures) but I don't known how to use them (someone could explain it to me?).

I can call ConcurrentHashMap methods:

- elements method obtaining an `Enumeration<V>`
- values method obtaining a `Collection<V>`and therefore an iterator

Which solutions is better?

Comment: what does your hashmap key and values contain? like what is there type?

Comment: Stream, filter, and then act on the results. In general this is an application of the stream and function api introduced in Java 8, which would be worth reading up on.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it but I don't know  why it was deleted

Comment: @Denis I edited question for you, to show you how you can use ` backtick to have part of the text look like code, and for that text to not treat characters like `<` and `>` as special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily iterate over a `map` keys or values with a `for each loop`,example:

```
Map<String,Document> chm=new ConcurrentHashMap<String,document>();
//this for each loop will iterate over the values of the map
//to iterate over the keys you write: for(String str : chm.keySet())
for(Document doc : chm.values()){
   // code to delete the document 
   // example(if your Document exposes a delete method): doc.delete();
}
```

As you can see in a `for each loop` you first declare the type of the objects: `String`,`int`,`Document` etc...

The 2nd part is your local variable, for example in the above case doc will be every `Document` in your `map` and you can call any method regarding it.

The 3rd part is the `:` and you can think of it as the word "in"

The last part is what you want to iterate over, in the above case it's the `map`'s values

The main difference between Enumeration and Iterator interface is that Enumeration only traverse the Collection object, you can't do any modifications to the collection when your iterating using Enumeration. Where as Iterator interface allows you to remove an element while traversing the Collection object(using the `remove()` method).

Comment: It looks simple! Thanks! Could you explain forEach method? I want to learn how to use it

Comment: this is the for each loop in java, do you want me to give an example of ```Enumaration<T>``` and the standard ```for loop```?

Comment: Sorry I mean this method void forEach(long parallelismThreshold, BiConsumer<? super K,? super V> action) but someone else answer me

Answer (score 1):

The `forEach` method takes a `BiConsumer` as the argument, where the inputs to the consumer are key and value pairs in the map:

```
void forEach(long parallelismThreshold, BiConsumer<? super K,? super V> action)
```

The `forEachValue` method takes a `Consumer` as the argument, where the inputs to the consumer are *only* the values in the map:

```
void forEachValue(long parallelismThreshold, Consumer<? super V> action)
```

In each method you can define the `parallelismThreshold` which from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) states:

> These bulk operations accept a parallelismThreshold argument. Methods proceed sequentially if the current map size is estimated to be less than the given threshold. Using a value of Long.MAX_VALUE suppresses all parallelism.

So use `forEach` if you need the key and the value, and use `forEachValue` if you only want the values:

e.g

```
myMap.forEach(Long.MAX_VALUE, (key, document) -> deleteDocument(key, document));
...

public void deleteDocument(String key, Document d) { ... }
```

or:

```
myMap.forEachValue(Long.MAX_VALUE, document -> deleteDocument(document));
...

public void deleteDocument(Document d) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks so much for documentation link. I don't know why in documentation i found didn't appear these method! I read it and now all is clear!

Comment: @Denis one of the nice things about Java is that the core libraries almost always have super helpful documentation!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do something with every value in the [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), you have many choices:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Document> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Document doc = entry.getValue();
    // code here
}

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    // code here
}

for (Document doc : map.values()) {
    // code here
}
```

```
map.forEach((key, doc) -> {
    // code here
});

map.forEach(1, (key, doc) -> {
    // code here will run in parallel
});

map.forEachEntry(1, entry -> {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Document doc = entry.getValue();
    // code here will run in parallel
});

map.forEachKey(1, key -> {
    // code here will run in parallel
});

map.forEachValue(1, doc -> {
    // code here will run in parallel
});
```

The above examples uses lambda expression *blocks*, but if the `code here` is just a single statement, you can omit the `{}` braces and the `;` statement terminator, and keep everything on one line, making it appear much cleaner, e.g.

```
map.forEachValue(Long.MAX_VALUE, doc -> DocUtil.deleteFile(doc));
```

Or use a method reference:

```
map.forEachValue(Long.MAX_VALUE, DocUtil::deleteFile);
```

Which of all the above you prefer is entirely up to you, and depends partially on whether you need `key`, `doc`, or both, and whether you need parallel processing.

Parallel processing probably doesn't improve performance when delete files, since that may require disk access, but if performance is critical, you can try to run in parallel and see for yourself whether that helps.

Comment: Thanks! your answer is so exhaustive.